# HAproxy redirect all root requests to www

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I have just installed HAproxy on a server which should do nothing to serve as  redirection endpoint of any incoming naked domain request (http and https), to the `www.`-version. Just like the service wwwizer.com. This is my cfg:

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http
        bind *:80
        bind *:443

        acl has_www hdr_beg(host) -i www
        http-request redirect code 301 location www.%[hdr(host)]%[req.uri] unless has_www
```

I have the A record of my domain DNS pointing to the IP of the server. However if I goto `http://exmaple_url.com` I get forwarded to: `http://exmaple_url.com/www.exmaple_url.com` instead of just `http://www.exmaple_url.com`

What am I doing wrong?

I followed the instruction in the documentation: https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/http_redirection.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect adding `https://` to the redirect location is the fix you need:

`http-request redirect code 301 location https://www.%[hdr(host)]%[req.uri] unless has_www`

Answer (score 0):

Update for anyone using this answer. The spec must have changed, and I needed to use this modified http-request to work:

```
http-request redirect code 301 location https://www.%[hdr(host)]%[capture.req.uri] unless has_www
```

Per section 7.3.6. of the docs  regarding req.uri:
https://www.haproxy.org/download/2.4/doc/configuration.txt

This is my experience with HA-Proxy version 2.3.9-53945bf 2021/03/30